# Active Record query when some conditions are absent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following hash conditions for retrieving `products` from the database:

```
@products = Product.where(category: @category, color: params[:color], brand_id: params[:brand], size: params[:size]).
```

Is there a way to get the query result when one or more of the conditions are not supplied, for example 
if `params[:color]` is absent, how can i retrieve the products with the other conditions?, or how can i restructure the conditions to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to base myself on techvineet's answer (editing was becoming messy).

Try this:

```
# This line throws away the :action and :controller arguments
params.except!(:action, :controller) # notice the ! now
params.delete_if {|k,v| v.nil?} # throw out any empty args
params[:category] = @category
@products = Product.where(params)
```

Comment: This almost works, there is a slight problem, it retrieves only one product. When i check the server logs, the generated SQL query looks like this: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products WHERE products.brand_id = 1 AND products.id = 1 AND products.category_id = 1`. I guess the problem is the `products.id = 1` which i dont know where it is coming from. Please assist.

Comment: product id is somehow generated as part of the form sent to the server. On the page it's generated from, look for any id or product id that is still part of (or nested in) the form that is being generated and remove it. You're right, that's exactly what's limiting your results to 1.

Comment: I have not created any form, I am typing the url directly on the address bar. I am calling `@products` from `categories#show` and not  `products#index` i'm not sure whether that makes any difference. I am typing this url: `http://localhost:3000/categories/1?brand_id=1` but for some reason it adds `product.id = 1` in the query.

Comment: You got me there. I think that since you're looking for products from the categories controller (if you are), then you're somehow using the category's "id" parameter to search for your product and confusing the two. Check for that.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use something like this:-

```
params.except(:action, :controller)
params[:category] = @category
@products = Product.where(params)
```

Comment: when i use this i get this error: `Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'products.action' in 'where clause': SELECT `products`.* FROM `products` WHERE `products`.`brand_id` = 1 AND `products`.`action` = 'show' AND `products`.`controller` = 'categories' AND `products`.`id` = 1 AND `products`.`category_id` = 1`

Comment: @techvineet you gave the best answer and I started editing it but didn't want to mess yours up. I used your answer as a basis for mine. I hope that's alright bro. You deserve the credit.

Comment: @techvineet blessings, I did.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Periscope gem](https://github.com/laserlemon/periscope)

Or [Ransack](https://github.com/ernie/ransack)

Answer (score 1):

You can build your query using conditions like this:

```
product_scope = Product.where(:category => @category)
product_scope = product_scope.where(:color => params[:color]) if params[:color]
# (...)

@products = product_scope.all
```

That way, only the valid and present conditions are being added to the scope. Or you could build a hash with your options in a similar way and add only the keys with valid params, then call `Product.where(conditions_hash).all`